# How do I position the caret inside a span element that has no text inside of it yet?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, contenteditable, caret

Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28891603/) SO post, I am able to place the caret inside a `span` element, which is inside a `div contenteditable="true"`.

I am able to target whichever `span` I desire, via its `id`, while also being able to decide which character should the caret be placed after.

But how can I place the caret inside a span that has no text inside?

Simply using the function, as is, gets me this error: `TypeError: Range.setStart: Argument 1 is not an object.`

Also, for some reason, when the `span` has content, it works fine, in Firefox. But not in Chrome, where the caret is placed outside the `span`. Any way to also solve this problem?

I am open to jQuery, if it makes things easier.

Here is my code:

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uos54wmx/1/)

```js
function setCaret(x, y) {
   var element = document.getElementById(x);
   var range = document.createRange();  
   var node;   
   node = document.getElementById(y);  
   range.setStart(node.childNodes[0], 0);
   var sel = window.getSelection();
   range.collapse(true);
   sel.removeAllRanges();
   sel.addRange(range);
   element.focus();    
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

input {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  padding: 3px;
}

input:last-of-type {
  margin-top: 30px;
}

div {
  width: 300px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: solid 1px #000;
}

span {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="place caret" onclick="setCaret('editableDiv1', 'span1');">
<div id="editableDiv1" contenteditable="true" spellcheck="false">This one <span id="span1">is</span> working.</div>

<input type="button" value="place caret" onclick="setCaret('editableDiv2', 'span2');">
<div id="editableDiv2" contenteditable="true" spellcheck="false">This one <span id="span2"></span> is not.</div>
```

Comment: On Chrome, when I click the "place caret" button on the one that says it's working and start typing, what I type doesn't go in the `span`, it goes **before** the span (e.g., it's not bold). On Firefox what I type is within the span. So I hate to say it, but the code is already problematic even when the `span` has content.

Comment: Firefox here. Still haven't tested it in other browsers. Here, it works as intended. I click on the button, it moves the caret inside the span, and it stays there as I type.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53747581/after-range-setstart-new-characters-appear-in-previous-node

Comment: You can correct the first issue by checking if there's a child node and adding an empty text element if not: `if (node.childNodes.length === 0) {
    var t = document.createTextNode('');   
  node.appendChild(t);    
   }`  Can't help with the Chrome issue though :-(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's a nice trick with zero-width space that you may consider (look at at the code below) and CSS property `white-space: pre` that allows spaces to be "visible" when focused.

```js
function makeTextNode() {
    return document.createTextNode('​') // <-- there a zero-width space between quotes
}

function placeCaretInSpan() {
  const range = document.createRange()
  const editable = document.getElementById("editable")
  const span = editable.querySelector("span")
  if (span.childNodes.length === 0) {
    span.appendChild(makeTextNode()) // <-- you have to have something in span in order to place caret inside
  }
  range.setStart(span.childNodes[0], 1) // <-- offset by 1 to be inside SPAN element and not before it
  let selection = window.getSelection()
  range.collapse(true)
  selection.removeAllRanges()
  selection.addRange(range)
  editable.focus()
}
```

```css
span {
    font-weight: bold;
    background: yellow;
}
#editable:focus {
    white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
<div contenteditable="true" id="editable">This should be <span></span> editable.</div>
<button onclick="placeCaretInSpan()">place caret</button>
```

Comment: This works in Chrome, but the zero-width space will mess the navigation through the arrow keys. Is there any other alternative?

Answer (score 0):

try with OR operator, this will return the node if node.childNodes[0] is undefined:

```
 range.setStart(node.childNodes[0] || node, 0);
```

Comment: i am sorry, my answer is actually the same. I have not seen the rest of the answers. I clicked the fiddle and worked there... Besides that, the case of that question is that, `node.childNodes[0]` is `undefined`

Comment: Hi @PeterDarmis, do not worry ;), the same thing has happened to me many times :).

Answer (score 0):

The problem occurs in the second case because `span2` has no content and `node.childNodes[0]` becomes `undefined`. A small workaround is used in the below snippet. The only line changed in your code is this:

```
range.setStart(node.childNodes[0], 0);
```

and became

```
range.setStart((typeof node.childNodes[0] !== 'undefined' ? node.childNodes[0] : node), 0);
```

You can check the result below.

```js
function setCaret(x, y) {
   let element = document.getElementById(x);   
   let range = document.createRange();  
   let node = document.getElementById(y);  
   range.setStart((typeof node.childNodes[0] !== 'undefined' ? node.childNodes[0] : node), 0);
   let sel = window.getSelection();
   range.collapse(true);
   sel.removeAllRanges();
   sel.addRange(range);
   element.focus();    
}
```

```css
body {
  padding: 10px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

input {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
}

input:last-of-type {
  margin-top: 50px;
}

div {
  width: 300px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: solid 1px #000;
}

span {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="place caret" onclick="setCaret('editableDiv1', 'span1');">
<div id="editableDiv1" contenteditable="true" spellcheck="false">This one <span id="span1">is</span> working.</div>

<input type="button" value="place caret" onclick="setCaret('editableDiv2', 'span2');">
<div id="editableDiv2" contenteditable="true" spellcheck="false">This one <span id="span2"></span> is working also.</div>
```